# Optimising redundant else statement

Tags: c#, .net

I have this block of code :

```
if (duplicateVoucherChecker(voucher))
{
    DialogResult dialogResult = Messages.Question("Podany bon był już użyty na tej stacji", "Uwaga", false);

    if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
    {
        ViewTyped.PaymentValueEditor.Focus();
    }
    else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        Vouchers.Add(voucher);
        Payment.OriginalToPay = Payment.ToPay;
        ViewTyped.PaymentNumberEditor.Focus();
        ViewTyped.ChangeEditor.Focus();
    }
}
else
{
    Vouchers.Add(voucher);
    Payment.OriginalToPay = Payment.ToPay;
    ViewTyped.PaymentNumberEditor.Focus();
    ViewTyped.ChangeEditor.Focus();
}
```

How can I make this non-redundant?

I want to get rid of second else statement but I still want this else block to be done if `duplicateVoucherChecker(voucher)` returns `false`.

Comment: Sounds like a better fit for [codereview.se]

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `bool` to keep track if the dialog was not shown or the result was  Yes and only do that logic if it is `true`.

```
bool dialogNotShownOrYesPicked = true;
if (duplicateVoucherChecker(voucher))
{
    DialogResult dialogResult = Messages.Question(
        "Podany bon był już użyty na tej stacji", "Uwaga",
        false);
    if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
    {
        ViewTyped.PaymentValueEditor.Focus();
    }
    if (dialogResult != DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        dialogNotShownOrYesPicked = false;
    }       
}

if(dialogNotShownOrYesPicked)
{
    Vouchers.Add(voucher);
    Payment.OriginalToPay = Payment.ToPay;
    ViewTyped.PaymentNumberEditor.Focus();
    ViewTyped.ChangeEditor.Focus();
}
```

Comment: This will run the redundant code if `DialogResult` is not `No`, which is not what the original code does (same as Servy answer)

Comment: This won't compile, your if has "dialogShownAndNoPicked" but your bool is "dialogShownAndYesNotPicked"

Comment: @Mason11987 Also fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Nested `if` statements are conceptually the same as simply ANDing those operations:

```
if (duplicateVoucherChecker(voucher) &&
    Messages.Question("Podany bon był już użyty na tej stacji", "Uwaga",false) 
        == DialogResult.No)
{
    ViewTyped.PaymentValueEditor.Focus();
}
else
{
    Vouchers.Add(voucher);
    Payment.OriginalToPay = Payment.ToPay;
    ViewTyped.PaymentNumberEditor.Focus();
    ViewTyped.ChangeEditor.Focus();
}
```

Note that this runs the code in question anytime `Messages.Question` returns any value other than `No`, rather than just if it returns `Yes`.  If `Messages.Question` can return a value other than `Yes` or `No`, and you shouldn't run the code in question if it does, then the code that you have is about as good as you would want it to be; at best you could refactor the duplicated code out into a method.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to store the state of the `dialogResult` in case of duplicate voucher.

```
var addVoucher = true;
if (duplicateVoucherChecker(voucher))
{
    DialogResult dialogResult = Messages.Question("Podany bon był już użyty na tej stacji", "Uwaga", false);
    addVoucher = (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes);
    if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
    {
        ViewTyped.PaymentValueEditor.Focus();
    }
}
if (addVoucher)
{
    Vouchers.Add(voucher);
    Payment.OriginalToPay = Payment.ToPay;
    ViewTyped.PaymentNumberEditor.Focus();
    ViewTyped.ChangeEditor.Focus();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use meaningful variables to store a state. If you have repeating code that is also an indication that you could create reusable methods, f.e. `AddVoucher`.

In this case you  could use a `bool` variable as flag:

```
bool duplicateVoucher = duplicateVoucherChecker(voucher);
bool addVoucher = !duplicateVoucher;
if(!addVoucher)
{
    DialogResult dialogResult = Messages.Question("Podany bon był już użyty na tej stacji", "Uwaga", false);
    addVoucher = dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes;
    if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)     
    {
        ViewTyped.PaymentValueEditor.Focus();
    }
}
if(addVoucher)
{
    Vouchers.Add(voucher);
    Payment.OriginalToPay = Payment.ToPay;
    ViewTyped.PaymentNumberEditor.Focus();
    ViewTyped.ChangeEditor.Focus();
}
```